# How to rearrange child divs on data attribute by recent date time in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, each

I have set each section with its own category name and wanted to rearrange its child div elements based on the `data` attribute sorted by recent date time published at the top then descending to the bottom.

I'm trying to loop through each of the child elements of its parent but the function `reArrangeVideosByRecentUploads()` isn't working. I debugged it and it would stop at this line of code `$('.section' + ALPHA_CLASS_NAME + ' .thumb .video-thumbnail').each(function(i) {` and then skip the function entirely. There's no error in the code, so I'm not sure why this is the case.

```js
var dates = [];
var _old;

var ALPHA_CLASS_NAME = ".alpha";
var BRAVO_CLASS_NAME = ".bravo";
var CHARLIE_CLASS_NAME = ".charlie";

function sortDates(a, b) {
  return new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime();
}

function reArrangeVideosByRecentUploads() {
  if ($(this).parent('.section' + ALPHA_CLASS_NAME)) {
    $('.section' + ALPHA_CLASS_NAME + ' .thumb .video-thumbnail').each(function(i) {
      _old = $(this).parent();
      dates.push($(this).data('date'));

      sorted = dates.sort(sortDates);
      _new = $('<div/>').insertBefore(_old);

      $.each(sorted, function(i, val) {
        $('div[data-date="' + val + '"]').appendTo(_new);
      });

      _old.remove();
    });
  } else if ($(this).parent('.section' + BRAVO_CLASS_NAME)) {
    $('.section' + BRAVO_CLASS_NAME + ' .thumb .video-thumbnail').each(function(i) {
      _old = $(this).parent();
      dates.push($(this).data('date'));

      sorted = dates.sort(sortDates);
      _new = $('<div/>').insertBefore(_old);

      $.each(sorted, function(i, val) {
        $('div[data-date="' + val + '"]').appendTo(_new);
      });

      _old.remove();
    });
  } else if ($(this).parent('.section' + CHARLIE_CLASS_NAME)) {
    $('.section' + CHARLIE_CLASS_NAME + ' .thumb .video-thumbnail').each(function(i) {
      _old = $(this).parent();
      dates.push($(this).data('date'));

      sorted = dates.sort(sortDates);
      _new = $('<div/>').insertBefore(_old);

      $.each(sorted, function(i, val) {
        $('div[data-date="' + val + '"]').appendTo(_new);
      });

      _old.remove();
    });
  }
}

reArrangeVideosByRecentUploads();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="alpha">
  <h1>
    Alpha
  </h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2012-04-02T13:04:48.000Z">A1 - 4/2012</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-06-30T21:21:16.000Z">A2 - 6/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2013-03-05T18:35:47.000Z">A3 - 3/2013</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-01-24T15:20:14.000Z">A4 - 1/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-12T17:25:43.000Z">A5 - 5/12/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-19T08:32:24.000Z">A6 - 5/19/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2020-02-03T22:05:25.000Z">A7 - 2/2020</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-31T18:13:21.000Z">A8 - 5/31/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2014-01-24T17:00:02.000Z">A9 - 1/2014</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="bravo">
  <h1>
    Bravo
  </h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2013-03-05T18:35:47.000Z">B1 - 3/2013</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-01-24T15:20:14.000Z">B2 - 1/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-12T17:25:43.000Z">B3 - 5/12/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-19T08:32:24.000Z">B4 - 5/19/2016</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="charlie">
  <h1>
    Charlie
  </h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2012-04-02T13:04:48.000Z">C1 - 4/2012</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-06-30T21:21:16.000Z">C2 - 6/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-31T18:13:21.000Z">C3 - 5/31/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2014-01-24T17:00:02.000Z">C4 - 1/2014</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/bug7n61v/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this a little. To sort elements you can use the `sort()` method. Provide this method a function which accepts two arguments which are the elements in the iteration to compare to each other. Convert the `data-date` values to `Date` objects and compare them, returning `1` or `-1` depending on which is the most recent.

To keep the logic DRY you can loop over all the `section .thumb` containers and sort them individually. Try this:

```js
$('section .thumb').each(function() {
  $(this).find('div').sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).data('date')) < new Date($(b).data('date')) ? 1 : -1;
  }).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="alpha">
  <h1>Alpha</h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2012-04-02T13:04:48.000Z">A1 - 4/2012</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-06-30T21:21:16.000Z">A2 - 6/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2013-03-05T18:35:47.000Z">A3 - 3/2013</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-01-24T15:20:14.000Z">A4 - 1/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-12T17:25:43.000Z">A5 - 5/12/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-19T08:32:24.000Z">A6 - 5/19/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2020-02-03T22:05:25.000Z">A7 - 2/2020</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-31T18:13:21.000Z">A8 - 5/31/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2014-01-24T17:00:02.000Z">A9 - 1/2014</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="bravo">
  <h1>Bravo</h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2013-03-05T18:35:47.000Z">B1 - 3/2013</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-01-24T15:20:14.000Z">B2 - 1/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-12T17:25:43.000Z">B3 - 5/12/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-19T08:32:24.000Z">B4 - 5/19/2016</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="charlie">
  <h1>Charlie</h1>
  <div class="thumb">
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2012-04-02T13:04:48.000Z">C1 - 4/2012</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2011-06-30T21:21:16.000Z">C2 - 6/2011</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2016-05-31T18:13:21.000Z">C3 - 5/31/2016</div>
    <div class="video-thumbnail" data-date="2014-01-24T17:00:02.000Z">C4 - 1/2014</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. One issue I have with this code is that after this code is executed and I have new additional divs being printed/appended to the category via jQuery, I notice it would take that new div just printed and append it to the top when in fact, the date is older than the ones already printed. I want to be able to recheck all the child divs against its date time attribute within the category and rearrange again. Is there a way to that?

Comment: Sure, just put this logic in a function and call it when new divs are added